# ev3dev vs lejos - looking for a comprehensive comparison

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, ev3dev, lejos

Did anyone make a good comparison of these two environments?

The most important factors to me are OS booting time, RAM usage, application start-up time,, compatibility with USB devices, and power consumption.

As an example, lejos takes 1:20s to boot up and obtain IP address and leaves 4812 kilobytes of free memory.